# Is the signature in PGP compressed as well, or just the contents of the message?

Tags: pgp, compression

I am developing an implementation of OpenPGP, and I'm using Kleopatra to test my generated messages.

After generating a signature for a message, I compress both the message and signature, but upon decrypting it in Kleopatra, it's treated as an unsigned document, returning to me decrypted and decompressed message with the signature attached.

I see many guides showing the PGP message structure similarly to the one I've attached , which imply that the signature should be compressed, but Kleopatra seems to disagree.

[image: PGP message structure]

So, which variant is the correct one? The one with a compressed signature or the one with an uncompressed one?

Comment: Have you consulted the RFC?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't explicitly clarify. Beyond explaining how it encrypts data, and how it follows after a signature, it has this to say in 11.3: 
"[...]decompressing a Compressed Data packet must yield a valid OpenPGP
   Message."
but it also defines an OpenPGP Message like this: "OpenPGP Message :- Encrypted Message | Signed Message | Compressed Message | Literal Message." so it could go either way, I suppose. In general it gives a vague leaning towards it being just the data.

Comment: Signatures are high entropy they wouldn't get compressed well if we tried

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After trying both ways, the only way I could accomplish compatibility with Kleopatra is by **compressing the signature as well**.

It was likely a bug in my code that made it behave as if it were unsigned. The final version of the code I used for both of those steps is shown below.

```
            File tempMsg = new File("tempMsg.asc");
            tempMsg.createNewFile();
            OutputStream tempOut = new FileOutputStream(tempMsg);
            signatureGenerator= new PGPSignatureGenerator(signerBuilder);
            try {
                signatureGenerator.init(PGPSignature.BINARY_DOCUMENT, senderKey.getPrivateKey());
            } catch (PGPException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            zipOut = tempOut;
            if(toCompress){
                zipGenerator = new PGPCompressedDataGenerator(CompressionAlgorithmTags.ZIP);
                zipOut = zipGenerator.open(tempOut);
            }

            try {
                signatureGenerator.generateOnePassVersion(false).encode(zipOut);
            } catch (PGPException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }

            OutputStream literalTempOut;
            
            literalTempOut = new PGPLiteralDataGenerator().open(zipOut, PGPLiteralDataGenerator.BINARY,inputFile);

            int data;

            //zip the data and update the signature 
            while((data = msgIn.read()) != -1){
                literalTempOut.write(data);
                signatureGenerator.update((byte)data);

            }

            //zip the signature and attach it to the previously zipped data
            try {
                signatureGenerator.generate().encode(zipOut);
            } catch (PGPException e) {
                throw new RuntimeException(e);
            }
```